# Responsive margin positioning issue in safari

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive-design

I have a sort of responsive website where elements are defined as:

```
 a#about{
     margin-left: 10.7%;
     margin-top: 18.8%;
     position: absolute;
     width: 7.4%;
 }
```

This works great to maintain the aspect ratio of the element for any resolution. However in Safari everything is moved far up the screen. I have reset my styles as well. Is there a known margin positioning issue with Safari ? The reason I am not using top and left, is because the object does not scale properly in relation to the window size

**EDIT:**

Here is an example to illustrate the different display in browsers 
Safari - FF/IE/Chrome [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsR6A/)

Comment: hmm this is strange indeed, it almost seems that safari has its own percentages. More research is needed. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a height, sometimes when using position absolute width and height are required for the box element to use other properties like margins and paddings.
I also see that this is being applied to an anchor, make the anchor a block to use the box model, `display:block`

Comment: Applied `display:block` but does not change anything. `margin-top` does not display the same distance as other browsers